# Split the value of a string from Pandas dataframe; and create a combination of the values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column that contains a formula

Case 1  ABC+(DEF/GHI/...)

Case 2     (ABC/DEF)+(GHI/JKL)

There are more cases but I listed only the above since it was the most complicated I have encountered

Legend:

"+"     = AND (code A and B)

"/"     = OR  (code A or B)

"( )"   = logical grouping

My goal is to split the value of the string into separate dataframe; and then create a combination of the values

Example result

Case 1  ABC+(DEF/GHI/...)

```
ABC + DEF
ABC + GHI
ABC + ...
```

Case 2  (ABC/DEF)+(GHI/JKL)

```
ABC + GHI
ABC + JKL 
DEF + GHI
DEF + JKL
```

Appreciate any guide on how I can approach the above problem

Comment: I'd make a list of groups by splitting over '+', then split each of the groups over '/' to obtain a list of lists, then use `itertools.product`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do this; I actually didn't use regex-es, but `split` and `strip` to parse the entry; I separated the process into several steps so you can observe the effect of each step:

```
from itertools import product

a = '(ABC) + (DEF/GHI) + (JKL/MNO/PQR)'

b = a.split('+')
c = [ group.strip().strip('(').strip(')').split('/') for group in b]
d = list(product(*c))
e = [' + '.join(l) for l in d]

e
# ['ABC + DEF + JKL',
#  'ABC + DEF + MNO',
#  'ABC + DEF + PQR',
#  'ABC + GHI + JKL',
#  'ABC + GHI + MNO',
#  'ABC + GHI + PQR']
```

I didn't actually work on a DataFrame, but on an individual string value, but you can wrap all this into a function and `apply` it to your df.

Comment: Many thanks @Swifty. I will work on to apply it to my dataframe